# Compilation error with platform/android-8 doesn't exit with android-3

Tags: android

I am trying to compile a file using gcc from Android toolchain. For some reason, when including 
android-ndk-r8//platforms/android-3/arch-arm/usr/include, it is compiled.  However, when using andriod-8 
android-ndk-r8//platforms/android-8/arch-arm/usr/include, it gives me this error:
error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
The problem is regarding refrences fields of struct tm. i.e.

```
struct tm *t;
t->tm_hour;
```

Any ideas?
Thanks